# Restrict selection of SELECT option without disabling the field

Tags: html, user-interface, html-select

I have a multiple selection SELECT field which I don't want the end user to be able to change the value of.

For UI reasons, I would like to be able to do this without using the disabled="true" attribute. I've tried using onmousedown, onfocus, onclick and setting each to blur or return false but with no success.

Can this be done or am I trying to do the impossible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know you mentioned that you don't want to, but I actually think that using the `disabled` attribute is a better solution:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="volvo" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab" disabled="disabled">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel" disabled="disabled">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi" disabled="disabled">Audi</option>
</select>
```

If necessary, you can always give the `select` a `class` and style it with CSS. This solution will work in all browsers regardless of scripting capabilities.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work in IE7.  I can still select them.  In Firefox they are disabled.

Comment: Damn IE. I wonder if there's an MS-specific equivalent to disabled="disabled"? Maybe readonly="readonly"?

Comment: No, there is none. They implemented the HTML4 disabled attribute in ie8 rc2 FIRST TIME

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to swap out the options within the select box.  If you only have one answer in that box, it doesn't matter if it is clickable.

I would, however,  try to find another way of doing this as it seems like it would cause frustration for a user.  Imagine this user scenario:

1. "Look, a select box of options."
2. *click*
3. "Hrm, why didn't that work?"
4. *click*
5. ***click***!
6. "This stupid thing is broken, I'm never coming back here."

If you swap out the select for HTML text, it accomplishes the same goal.  This is a fairly simple task for most of the major Javascript frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Could you do it with an `onchange` event?

```
<select onfocus="this.oldIndex=this.selectedIndex" onchange="this.selectedIndex=this.oldIndex">
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jack & @17 of 26, good point but the end user will be expecting the select box to be disabled so that confusion shouldn't be an issue.

I should have been clearer about why I couldn't just disable the control.

The application that will be using this will need to disable the selection of the options and there is a requirement that the "locked" control still maintain the look and feel of normal form controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trigger.

```
<select multiple onchange="this.selectedIndex=this.selectedIndex">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent new addition to CSS3 that is [95% compatible](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) with all current browsers except Opera Mini, called `pointer-events`. Put simply, you can "disable" the default action on a `SELECT` or any other element, and still be able to perform specific events on it...

You can view Chris Coyier's article on them at [enter link description here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/).

Is this closer to what you're looking for... Sorry that I couldn't provide any of my own coding examples...